# Resizable UICollectionViewCell using Autolayout

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, autolayout, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a UICollectionView with constraints set in Interface Builder. The CollectionView's size adjusts according to the screen size.

I want a grid of equally sized square cells within the CollectionView, which resizes after their superview's size. I want to be able to change both the amount of cells and the padding between them, and let Autolayout take care of the sizing.

I've thought a bit about this, but I'm not really sure were to start. I would really appreciate some input!

Thanks

[image: Example photo]
[image: Example photo 2]

Comment: What constraints in IB are you talking about? For the subviews of the cell? I don't think you can use auto layout to size the cells themselves. You'll need to calculate the itemSize based on the collection view size and the number of cells you want per line (taking into account the padding).

Comment: It doesn't have to be constraints set in IB, could be in code. I was thinking on the cells contentViews. Maybe that they would have a equal width and height constraint, and a padding constraint between each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work using https://github.com/rhodgkins/RDHCollectionViewGridLayout

Just needed to set a few parameters depending on layout. Works for all screen sizes.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you could do this in Interface Builder, but you can always use the VFL to set constraints with values derived dynamically from the size of the container view. The call you want is [`NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:attribute:relatedBy:toItem:attribute:multiplier:constant:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutConstraint_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSLayoutConstraint/constraintWithItem:attribute:relatedBy:toItem:attribute:multiplier:constant:).

Comment: I was thinking about that approach, but I'm not sure what values I would set in able to get the result I want. I'm not asking for someone to do it for me, just a kick in right direction. Maybe setting a constraint for equal size and height, and then one for padding in between the cells? Also, where is a good place to set these constraints?

Comment: I prefer to set constraints in IB unless they need to be handled dynamically in code.

Comment: And it may be as simple as what you're suggesting: equal heights and widths, and padding. I'd just be sure to specify min and max ranges, as applicable, so that you don't wind up with cells that are too tiny or wider than the collection view.